# How to make volume rocker affect media volume when app is in foreground?

Tags: android, media, volume, foreground

I would like to have the volume rocker affect media volume when app is in foreground. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [volume controls documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/volume-and-earphones.html#volume-controls):

> To ensure that volume controls adjust the correct stream, you should call [`setVolumeControlStream()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setVolumeControlStream(int)) passing in [`AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#STREAM_MUSIC).

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

Comment: Thanks @ianhanniballake. Do I have to set that in every activity?

Comment: Yes, if you want the volume to be adjusted before you start playback.